# pid resources consumption

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, pid

Please help me in finding a good way to export a process resources use. To be more specific:

I have a c# program used as a test-stress client for a rest-ful web application. In that C# program I run 30 threads simultaneously.

This logging program should be able to write on a file, each second:
-processor load
-memory used

Any solution written in bash would be of a great help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use vmstat utility for CPU load measurement and ps to measure the CPU utilization per process.

Unfortunately I do not remember exactly the command line options that you have to send but I am sure you can find them yourself easily.

I implemented similar task several years ago. I ran vmstat (with required command line options) in background and read its output. So, I had the overall cpu and memory utilization. 
BTW vmstat "knows" to run periodically, so you even do not have to implement your own loop. 
Additionally I ran ps (with required parameters) that measured CPU of interesting process.

Bottom line: there is 10% of java and 90% of shell scripting here.

And the last note. The overall CPU utilization may be discovered using pure java:
`ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean().getSystemLoadAverage()`

This returns system load average in last minute. So, if 1 min resolution is good for you use this instead of vmstat. Otherwise vmstat is your solution.

Comment: for the memory (RSS) I use now /proc/pid/stat data, for the cpu I used ps -Lp pid opcpu but it seems to return just snapshots of the load, not a real time reliable data. Thanks anyway for the answer, I read it at that moment, sorry for the delay in response